# Find max product of 2 subarray split from 1 array

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, big-o, biginteger

I have a problem.

Give an `arr` array of integers. Let's divide this array into 2 consecutive subarrays so that the sum of the product of the products in these two arrays is the greatest. Since the result can be very large, it will be divided by a remainder of `10^9+7`

[Input] array of integers
`2 <= arr.length <= 10^4`.
`|arr[i]| <= 10^4`.

For example:

- For `arr = [2,4,1,3]` then `maxProduct(arr) = 14`.

Explanation: we can divide into two sub arrays `[2]` and `[4,1,3]`.

- For `arr = [-1,3,4, -2]` then `maxProduct (arr) = -11`.

Explanation: we can divide into two sub arrays `[-1,3]` and `[4, -2]`

Here's my solution:

```
    def mul(arr):
        r = 1
        for i in arr:
            r*=i
        return r
    
    def maxProduct(arr):
        res_max = mul(arr[0:1]) +mul(arr[1:])
        for i in range(1,len(arr)):
            first_half = arr[0:i]
            after_half = arr[i:]
            t = mul(first_half) + mul(after_half)
            if res_max<t:res_max=t
        return res_max
```

However, it can be handle the big number.
I am looking for efficient solution.

Comment: Can you include the original link from the source?

Comment: Original source is Vietnamese: [link](https://codelearn.io/fightstask/index?id=6237480&taskid=6229973)

The English version I have post above. This is another testcase: 
Input: [-1,3,4,-2] 
Output: -11;
Input: [-4,-10,10,10,2]
Output:4002 ;
Input: [10,-2,-8,3,-5,-4,-10,10,-1,8]
Output: 960008 
@DanielHao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a time complexity of `O(N^2)`, which needs to be reduced.
Consider an array `product`, where `product[i] = arr[0]*arr[1]....*arr[i]`. This array can be computed in `O(N)` with one pass. Now, you need to split your array in two consecutive parts. Let's consider the subarrays to be `arr[0 to i-1]` and `arr[i:]`, for a given `i`. We can loop from `i=n-2` to `i=1`, and see where we get the maximum sum.

```py
mod = int(1e9)+7
arr = [2,4,1,3]
n = len(arr)
product_array = [0]*n
product_array[0] = arr[0]

for i in range(1,n):
    product_array[i] = product_array[i-1]*arr[i]

ans = float("-inf")
right_product = arr[n-1]
left_product = product_array[n-2]
ans = left_product+right_product

for i in range(n-2,0,-1):
    right_product = right_product*arr[i]
    left_product = product_array[i-1]
    curr_sum = left_product+right_product
    ans = max(ans, curr_sum)

print(ans%mod)
```

Comment: It's a better way. But there is a problem when working with negative number. For example: Input: [-1,3,4,-2], the output must be -11. With that code above, the output is 999999996

Comment: @SonHaNguyen You've added a condition that "Since the result can be very large, it will be divided by a remainder of 10^9+7". Take ```(-11) mod 1e9+7``` and you'll get that answer itself. If that's an issue, remove the modulus?

Comment: Good analysis and faster O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem in this way.

```
import numpy as np

def get_max_product(a):
    # Defining initial conditions to beat
    maxv = sum([np.prod(a[:1]),np.prod(a[1:])])
    best_i = 1
    # Iterating the array trying to beat the initial conditions
    for i in range(2,len(a)):
        sumprod = sum([np.prod(a[:i]),np.prod(a[i:])])
        # Updating best scenario in a better one found
        if sumprod > maxv:
            maxv,best_i = sumprod,i
    
    return a[:best_i],a[best_i:]

get_max_product([2,4,1,3])
```

Comment: How is this O(N)?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur hi, what would be from your point of view and why?. By the way no challenge, just really would like to know.

Comment: From what I know, ```np.prod(a[:i])``` takes O(N) time. Calling that N times should be O(N^2)

Comment: @AbhinavMathur make sense. The calculation of the product becomes more complex depending on the length of the array. Removing that comment from my answer